# JqGrid BeforeShow event of add dialog variables reset

Tags: jqgrid, dialog, addition

I call the following function before the add dialog is shown; after clicking [+] on the JqGrid.

MVC Controller grid configuration

```
ordersGrid.ClientSideEvents.BeforeAddDialogShown = "initAddDialog";
```

The function makes an Ajax call to create a new order record either with or without a linking id, dependent on whether an existing order was selected when the [+] button was clicked.

The purpose is to make available the id necessary to make another Ajax call to retrieve additional linked information from another service, and to pre-populate the new record with date/time information and (where applicable) common information from an existing record.

```
function initAddDialog() {
var newOrderId = 0;
var newOrderLinkId = 0;
var selRow = jQuery('#clientOrderGrid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
var selRowData = jQuery('#clientOrderGrid').jqGrid('getRowData', selRow);
```

Get linking ID from selected row (if any)

```
var curOrderLinkId = (selRowData.OrderLinkId == null) ? 0 : selRowData.OrderLinkId;
```

Ajax call to create new 'Holding' Order

```
$.ajax({
url: '/Order/ajaxNewOrder?OrderLinkId=' + curOrderLinkId,
success: function (newOrderResponse) {
arr = newOrderResponse.split("|");
newOrderId = arr[0];
newOrderLinkId = arr[1];
},
error: function () { alert("There was an error creating an Order record"); }
});
```

If I break the code here using Firebug in Firefox, I can see that the variables newOrderId and newOrderLinkId have been set correctly with the id's from the newly created record, and if I hit F8 the (already displayed) dialog is populated with these //values.

If I don't break the code the dialog is displayed, but displays the values with which the variables were initialised i.e. newOrderId = 0, newOrderLinkId = 0.

```
$('#' + 'OrderId').val(newOrderId);
$('#' + 'OrderLinkId').val(newOrderLinkId);
$('#' + 'Stock').val(stock);
$('#' + 'SettlesTs').val(settlesTs);
$('#' + 'ReceivedTs').val(dtThis);
$('#' + 'ReceivedHHmm').val(dtTime);
```

I've tried calling the same function after the add dialog is shown, but get the same results.

Any thoughts as to why this is, or is there a better way of achieving the same result?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken the native add/edit dialog out of the equation and am using my own 'add' form along with the native inline editing of JqGrid. I'm sure with more research it would have been  possible to find a solution, but with deadlines looming I had to find a workaround.